# Django - Add field to queryset to store computation results

Tags: django, list, append

I'm pretty new to Django and come from the PHP world. I'm trying to 'add' a field to a queryset after computing things, and don't know how to do it. In PHP I would just add a column in an array and store my stuff in it.

Here's my code:

```
def (id):
    mystuff_details    = mystuff_details.objects.filter(stuff_id=id)
    newthing = '';
    for mystuff in mystuff_details:
        newthing_lists = //some query to get another queryset
        for newthing_list in newthing_lists:
            newthing = newthing_list.stuffIwant
            //Here I want to make some computation, and ADD something to newthing, let's say:  
            to_add = (mystuff.score+somethingelse)
            //I've heard about the .append but I'm sure I'm screwing it up
            newthing.append(to_add)
```

So basically in my template I'd like to be able to call:
    {% for newthing in newthings_list %}
       {{ newthing.to_add }}
    {% end %}

**TL;DR:** I basically want to retrieve a list of stuff from my database, and in this list of objects ADD a field that will contain a computed value.

Let me know if it's unclear, I'm having a hard time switching from php to django haha.

Thanks!

EDIT:

So, I'm trying with a dictionnary, but I must be missing the logic:

```
def (id):
    mystuff_details    = mystuff_details.objects.filter(stuff_id=id)
    newthing = {};
    for mystuff in mystuff_details:
        newthing_lists = //some query to get another queryset
        for newthing_list in newthing_lists:
            //Newthing_list can have several times the same I, and the scores need to add up
            if newthing[newthing_list.id] > 0: //This doesn't seem to work and throws an error (KeyError)
                newthing[newthing_list.id] = newthing[newthing_list.id] + some_calculated_thing
            else: 
                newthing[newthing_list.id] = some_calculated_thing
```

And then when I'll get that working, I don't know how to access it in the template:

```
 {% for id in my_list %}
     {{newthing[id]}} ? Or something like newthing.id ?
 {% end %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
newthing = {}
newthing['your_key'] = to_add
```

In the template, you can access dictionary values with:

```
{{newthing.your_key}}
```

Or use the for loop if you have a dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: Hello and thanks! I tried with dictionnaries, that's the part after the "edit" in my question, but no luck for now yet. What have I done wrong in my code? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, check out [writing views in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/). In your view, you have to return something like `return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
`

Answer (score 41):

You can set anything on a python object:

```
for obj in self.model.objects.all() :
    obj.score = total_score / total_posts
```

This will work even if obj does not have a score attribute. In the template request it like so:

```
{{ obj.score }}
```

Yes, it's that simple.
However, if the calculations you're doing can be done in the database, you should look into [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

Comment: I know some people may say this is too simple, but this is probably the best simple solution I've seen for this.

Comment: @ Melvyn This is this THE WAY to add calculated fields to Querysets

Answer (score 1):

If @Melvyn's solution doesnt work for you:

Ensure you don't call `.all()` etc on the queryset when modifying the queryset, as `.all()` returns a copy of the queryset, e.g.

```
qs = foo.objects.filter(bar=1); 
for obj in qs.all(): 
    obj.caz = 1;  # Will not persist
```

Now `qs` will remain unchanged.

Rather:

```
qs = foo.objects.filter(bar=1).all(); 
for obj in qs: 
    obj.caz = 1;
```

Now you can access `.caz` in the template.