# How to add new field to filtered query

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter

I'm trying to add a new column for which I need to do some operations based on other models in a FilterSet.

I have my view like this:

```
class FilteredListView(ListView):
    filterset_class = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        self.filterset = self.filterset_class(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
        return self.filterset.qs.distinct()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filterset'] = self.filterset
        querysetPaises = Pais.objects.all().filter(paisActivo=1).order_by('nombrePais')
        context['paises']=querysetPaises
        return context

class ListadoPartnerView(FilteredListView):
    filterset_class = PartnerFilter
    paginate_by = 10
    model = IngresosPersonas
    fields = ['idPlataforma', 'number_plataforma', 'contactoinfo']
    template_name = 'usuarios/listadoPartners.html'
```

And my filter is:

```
class PartnerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = IngresosPersonas
        fields = ['idPlataforma', 'number_plataforma']
```

Basically I want to include a new column on the filterset that the template receives which is not included in the model.

I've tried to access the filterset.qs but no luck

Many thanks

Comment: Here's your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12129934

Comment: If I do     for obj in filterset_class.model.objects.all():
        print(obj) I get the error type object 'PartnerFilter' has no attribute 'model'

Comment: I'm not sure about the context but I think what you're looking for is `filterset_class.objects.all()` and not `filterset_class.model.objects.all()`

Comment: Unfortunately type object 'PartnerFilter' has no attribute 'objects'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add non model field to FilterSet but you need manually specify [method](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#method) which will be triggered by this filter:

```
class PartnerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    new_field = django_filters.CharFilter(method="filter_new_field")
    class Meta:
        model = IngresosPersonas
        fields = ['idPlataforma', 'number_plataforma', 'new_field']

    def filter_new_field(self, queryset, name, value):
            return queryset.filter() # your extra filters here
```

If you need to add non model field on representation level (template) you can just define property in your model:

```
class MyMode(models.Model):
    @property
    def new_field(self):
        return "some value"
```

In template you can access this field like this `{{ obj.new_field }}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really need to filter by the new field, I want to include the new field on the list of objects that are returned to the template. Where do I need to make my operations to include it?

Comment: @AlbertoCarmona hm, in this case I suppose you can just add model's property.

Comment: Many thanks, worked flawlessly!!. Just for curiosity as an alternative, could I define a queryset and annotate a field instead of passing the model to the filter?

Comment: You are welcome! I suppose you can annotate it, you can use `Value` for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions